# Does a element with display:none set in css still get downloaded by the browser?

Tags: html, css

Will the browser still download the image?

```
<img src="/myimage.jpg" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: Suggest to change the title to "Does an image with display:none set in css still get downloaded by the browser?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at least according to the Net console in Firebug.

As stated by **thethimble**, CSS is the presentation layer and affects rendering, not the actual processing of the page.

It wouldn't be outside the realm of possibility for some browsers, especially mobile, to potentially not download this in an attempt to optimize performance.

Comment: I thought this was the case, just needed to convince a colleague.

Comment: Apparently Opera doesn’t. Test page: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/displayimg.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The rendering of the image has nothing to do with the downloading of the image.

Edit:
Try using Chrome or Firefox to perform a timing-test of a page's resources. Notice that all images get downloaded. Even ones whose display style is set to none.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

However, as a sidenote, some browsers won't download images with `width` and `height` attributes of 0. Can't find the source now, and just tested Firefox and Safari and they *do* download it. Must be IE, can anyone test for me? Thanks.

When in doubt, sniff the line, or use a browser specific tool (Firebug for Firefox, Web Inspector for Webkit, etc)

Answer (score 0):

[Quirks Mode: images and display: none](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/displayimg.html)

> When image has `display: none` or is inside an element with 
>   `display:none`, the browser may opt not to download the image until the `display`
>   is set to another value.
>
> Only Opera downloads the image when you switch the `display` to `block`.
>   All other browsers download it immediately.